# Getting 404 error for apache `/server-status`

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, apache2, ubuntu-22.04

I was told that there's a way to enable a url called `http://<your host>/server-status` and that this page would show you some operational metrics of the apache service.  But every time I visit that url, I get 404 page not found. Here's how I set things up:

1. Start a new virtual machine in my office network.  The local ip address of this machine is `192.168.0.42`. The machine uses Ubuntu 22.04.
2. I run `apt-get update && apt dist-upgrade -y && apt-get install -y apache2`.  This installs Apache 2.4.52.
3. The Windows computer I work from has the local ip address of `192.168.0.16`.  From this computer, I type `http://192.168.0.42` and I can see the Apache default web page.
4. On the machine of `192.168.0.42`, I type `a2enmod rewrite && a2enmod status`.
5. I provide the following files

`// /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
AccessFileName .htaccess
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


Include ports.conf
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

`/etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf && /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_status.c>
        # Allow server status reports generated by mod_status,
        # with the URL of http://servername/server-status
        # Uncomment and change the "192.0.2.0/24" to allow access from other hosts.

        <Location /server-status>
                SetHandler server-status
                Require local
                Require ip 192.168.0.42/24
                Require ip 192.168.0.16/24
        </Location>

        # Keep track of extended status information for each request
        ExtendedStatus On

        # Determine if mod_status displays the first 63 characters of a request or
        # the last 63, assuming the request itself is greater than 63 chars.
        # Default: Off
        #SeeRequestTail On


        <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
                # Show Proxy LoadBalancer status in mod_status
                ProxyStatus On
        </IfModule>


</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Next, I type `systemctl restart apache2` into the bash terminal of the `192.168.0.42` machine.

Next, when my `192.168.0.16` computer loads up `http://192.168.0.42/server-status` via google chrome browser, I get 404.

When I run the command `wget http://192.168.0.42/server-status` from the shell of `192.168.0.42`, I get 404.

When I run the command `wget http://127.0.0.1/server-status` from the shell of `192.168.0.42`, I get 404.

When I run the command `wget http://localhost/server-status` from the shell of `192.168.0.42`, I get 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IIRC if you have a virtualhost that location won't apply since it is defined in server context config and when a virtualhost is used that virtualhost will serve content not the server config, try to also include it in your virtualhost, check "apachectl -S" output for your defined virtualhosts